# TweetSharp exception if callback url contains IP Address

Tags: asp.net, tweetsharp, hammock

I may have stumbled onto a strange bug thats within either TweetSharp or Hammock. When trying to get an authorization token from Twitter via the normal routine of:

```
TwitterService service = new TwitterService(API_KEY,API_SECRET);
OAuthRequestToken request = service.GetRequestToken(GetCallBackUrl());
```

I've noticed that if the callback url contains an IP address instead of a machine name (localhost/SERVER1 etc), the page takes forever to load then an ArgumentNullException is thrown.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. 
Parameter name: query at System.Compat.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String query, Encoding encoding) 

in f:\src\hammock\src\net40\Hammock.ClientProfile\Mono\HttpUtility.cs:line 1220 at 
System.Compat.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String query) 
in f:\src\hammock\src\net40\Hammock.ClientProfile\Mono\HttpUtility.cs:line 1214 
at TweetSharp.TwitterService.GetRequestToken(String callback) 
in f:\src\tweetsharp\src\TweetSharp\TwitterService.OAuth.cs:line 173 
at TwitterForm.SetAuthUrl() 
at TwitterForm.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Once I switch back to the PC name, all seems fine, sometimes.
On most clients, switching to the Name works, on some however, it doesnt and keeps throwing the above error. I suspect the people for whom changing to the PC name doesn't work, may be the fact that they're using a proxy server. I'll keep troubleshooting.

For now I just wanted to know if anyone has a possible work-around or solution to this?

Comment: I have the same issue now, and really don't know how to fix it. I'm developing an MVC4 project with letting user to use OpenID from Twitter :(

Comment: Don't have much experience with OpenID on twitter so might not be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

In the end this bug turned out not to be caused by the IP Address but because of issues related to proxy server authentication. The account we were using to access the proxy server had a password that kept expiring, switching to an account with a fixed password resolved it.

Comment: Can you please dwell more on what the proxy issue was?

Comment: Sorry, over year later. The issue was authentication errors on the proxy server, we were using an account whose password kept expiring.

Comment: Thanks, and it will be more helpful to others if you add that in your answer.